# C# Directory Not Found Exception

Tags: c#

I am using VS 2015 Community and C# I am trying to read a JSON file stored inside folder called `lib` in the project as `lib/user.json`

```
 String jsonSTR = File.ReadAllText("lib/user.json");
```

but I am getting the Directory Not Found Exception

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the file doesn't exist. At least not where the program expects it to. Have you confirmed that it does? What's the absolute path to the file you're expecting the program to find?

Comment: I take for granted that you have already checked if the path exists right?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you put the `/lib/user.json` file as a child of the `bin/Debug` folder (or `bin/Release`, or whatever folder the app is launched from), because that's where the app will search for it, not in project's folder.

Comment: http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/ImageOfAnException

Comment: @Will Hadn't come across that site before. I like the idea.

Answer (score 3):

You should use reflection to get into relative path:

```
public static string PredictAbsoluteFilePath(string fileName)
{
    return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), fileName);
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
string path = Utils.PredictAbsoluteFilePath("relativeFile.xml");
//assuming that currect executing file is in D:\Programs\MyApp directory
//path is now 'D:\Programs\MyApp\relativeFile.xml'
```

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'd advocate for `Path.Combine()`: `return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), filename);`